# How to prevent prop drilling with SSR in Next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prop-drilling

I'm wondering how I can prevent prop drilling with SSR in the following situation:

Layout.tsx:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const user = await getUser(cookies().get("accessToken")?.value);

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Navigation user={user}
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Now imagine in `Navigation` there are multiple nested components that require the `user`. Normally I'd use the store to pass down data like this but now I'm a bit clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Call `getUser(cookies().get("accessToken")?.value)` in the child components**. This works because requests with the same path and input are automatically deduped by Next's polyfill of `fetch`.

From [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#automatic-fetch-request-deduping):

> If you need to fetch the same data (e.g. current user) in multiple components in a tree, Next.js will automatically cache fetch requests (GET) that have the same input in a temporary cache. This optimization prevents the same data from being fetched more than once during a rendering pass.

Note: if you are not using `fetch` then use Next's [cache feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/caching)

Comment: Good thing one of us can read the docs. :D